Unable to trigger the azure pipeline from another project pipeline completion
I am supposed to trigger a pipeline when a pipeline in another project completes. I have used the resource feature
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: ABC_Pipeline
    source: xyz
    project: pqr
    trigger:
      branches:
        - "*"

Although the source pipeline xyz is successful in pqr project the pipeline is not triggering.


the source pipeline xyz is successful in pqr project the pipeline is not triggering.

You can check the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds of the pipeline in pqr project(Navigate to Edit -> Triggers -> Yaml -> Get sources).

You need to make sure that the Yaml file in the default branch contains the correct Resource pipeline trigger.
Pipeline will use the resources trigger in the default branch of the YAML pipeline
If no, you need to change the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds to the correct branch.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: The pipeline default branch
